# How to call a Javascript function and pass a parameter in asp.net c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have an Array in aspx.cs file

```
string[] strArray3 = new string["Application Begin : <span style="color: 
green;">12/03/2020</span>","Last Date for Apply Online : <span style="color: 
red;">26/04/2020</span>","Pay Examination Fee Last Date : 28/04/2020","Exam Date : September 2020"]
```

This function is in my .js file.
I add input box through this function and put inside it array data.

```
function addRowWithData(stringArray, ids) {
        var takeControl;
        switch (ids){
            case "date":
                takeControl = document.getElementById("dateInput");
                break;
            case "fees":
                takeControl = document.getElementById("feesInput");
                break;
            case "age":
                takeControl = document.getElementById("ageInput");
                break;
        }
        takeControl.removeChild(takeControl.firstElementChild);
        for (var i = 0; i < stringArray.length; i++) {
            $("#" + takeControl.id).prepend("<input class=\"form-control mb-3\" name=\"'" + ids + "'InputBox\" type=\"text\" value=\"'" + stringArray[i] + "'\"/>");
        }
    
    }
```

Comment: Could you be more specific ? What exactly is your problem ?

Comment: Look into `RegisterClientScriptBlock` and `RegisterStartupScript`.

Comment: @MarleneHE, I have a string array strArray3 in csharp and i want to call js function addRowWithData from code behind, which have two parameters (stringArray, ids). and i want pass strArray3 when i will call addRowWithData function. And I want to know how to call it and how to pass strArray3 array.

Answer (score 0):

You **cannot call JavaScript from code behind.**

What you can do is to **render the function** you want to run, when you render the page, with any parameter that you like, and when the page renders on browser the javascript will run.

Alternative you can render the parameters on page direct on javascript part.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkMyText() {
        var args = '<%=Parameter%>');
        alert(args);
        }
</script>
```

and on code behind

```
public partial class OnePage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public string Parameter = "test";

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
}
```